# Update filter PIVOTTABLE depending on a cell value with Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, pivot-table

I am looking for a way to update a filter on my pivot table based on the value of a cell without having to recreate the whole pivot table.

Here is my current code:

```
function saturationTabDynamique() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceData = ss.getRange('Planning2!A1:L127');
  var pivotTable = ss.getRange('Saturation2!A3').createPivotTable(sourceData);
  var pivotGroup = pivotTable.addRowGroup(7).setDisplayName("Lib_Ligne");
  pivotGroup.showTotals(false);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addColumnGroup(2).setDisplayName("Date");
  pivotGroup.showTotals(false);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addColumnGroup(3).setDisplayName("Equipe").showTotals(false);
  pivotGroup.showTotals(false);
  pivotGroup = pivotTable.addColumnGroup(8).setDisplayName("Focus");
  pivotGroup.showTotals(false);
  var pivotValue = pivotTable.addPivotValue(11,SpreadsheetApp.PivotTableSummarizeFunction.AVERAGE).setDisplayName("MOYENNE");
  return pivotTable;

}



function onEdit(e){
  Logger.log("Ancienne valeur : "+e.oldValue);
  Logger.log("Valeur actualisée : "+e.value);
  Logger.log("Localisation de la modif" + e.range.getA1Notation());
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() == 'B1'){
    var update = saturationTabDynamique();
    var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setVisibleValues(['', e.value])
    .build();
     update.addFilter(1, criteria);
  }
}
```

Thanks for reading.

Comment: You need to use Sheets API and access the pivot table directly in the cell to update it. (reference: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/pivot-tables#PivotTable)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but once I have added Google Sheets API V4, where do I program to update my cell? Do I have to create a new Json file in which I make a "request"?